# Trigger the jQuery's keypress event on an input text

Tags: jquery, triggers, keydown

Regarding the [`.trigger()` method](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), the [`Event` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), the [`which` property](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/), the [JS char codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) and the code below, why does the `#example` input don't get the char `a` as *auto-written* value? Did I misunderstand the `.trigger()` method?

```
<input type="text" name="example" id="example" value="" />

<script>
$(function() {
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown", { which: 65 });
    $("#example").focus().trigger(e);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mistake you're making is what you're expecting the jQuery's `trigger` method to do. If you check out the [code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L232-379) you'll see that what it is doing is actually executing the jQuery registered event handlers **not** the DOM Level 3 events. Because it's only executing jQuery handlers you wont be causing the `change` event which is what you need to be triggered to update the value property of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

> Any event handlers attached with .bind() or one of its shortcut methods are triggered when the corresponding event occurs.

```
$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
$('#foo').trigger('click');
```

In your case, it would be:

```
$('#example').bind('keydown', function(e) {
  alert("Pressed: " + e.keycode());
});
$('#example').focus().trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be over simplifying things, but couldn't you simply alter the `.val()` (value) of the input field to simulate `auto-written values`?

You could simply set the value like this -

```
$("#example").val('Some auto-written value');
```

Of you could do something a little more visual like this -

```
var autoText = ['f','o','o','b','a','r'];
var characterIndex = 0;
var autoType = setInterval(function(){
  $("#example").val( $("#example").val() + autoText[characterIndex] );
  characterIndex++;
  if (characterIndex >= autoText.length){
    clearInterval(autoType);
  }
},_keystroke_interval);
```

The `_keystroke_interval` is the interval (in milliseconds) between the auto typed characters.  The `autoType` interval variable will iterate through all the indexes of the `autoText` array and for each iteration it will append one character to the input field.

This will give you more of an auto-typing feel...

[here is a **working jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/587At/3/)