# Trigger Google Places Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I am trying to attach a virtual keyboard to bind to a Google places autocomplete input.

If I physically type in a letter in the input, a Google-powered dropdown displays the autocomplete predictions based on where the map is centered. If I click on a virtual keyboard key, the input gets updated properly, but the autocomplete predictions are not updated.

I have tried to use the virtual keyboard `change` callback to trigger a "keyup" (stackoverflow results), "keypress", "keydown", "change" and I even tried this ([demo](http://jsbin.com/nojuy/3/edit?html,output)):

```
change : function(e, keyboard, el) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(autocomplete, 'place_changed');
}
```

which results in a javascript error basically showing that `autocomplete.getPlace();` does not return a result.

So now I've tried the code below (in [this demo](http://jsbin.com/nehobale/2/edit?html,output)), which uses the change callback to trigger an autocomplete prediction, but as you can see in that demo, the results differ.

```
change : function(e, keyboard, el) {
  var $el = $(el),
      service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  if ($el.val() !== "") {
    service.getQueryPredictions({ input: $(el).val() }, function(predictions, status) {
      if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
        return;
      }
      var list = '', $results = $('#results');
      for (var i = 0, prediction; prediction = predictions[i]; i++) {
        list += '<li>' + prediction.description + '</li>';
      }
      $results.html(list);
    });
  }
}
```

Ideally, I want to trigger the already established autocomplete prediction dropdown to update while typing on the virtual keyboard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid need for end-user to manually start the Google Places Autocomplete dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892092/how-to-avoid-need-for-end-user-to-manually-start-the-google-places-autocomplete)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found my answer ([demo](http://jsbin.com/nehobale/5/edit?html,output))!

```
change : function(e, keyboard, el) {
    google.maps.event.trigger( el, 'focus', {} );
}
```

Comment: Dude, you ended up hours of wandering among Google's API. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you guys figure out how to trigger the change when I click on the autocomplete results? I can get the 'focus' to trigger and display the results but now when I click on the results, they don't go away.

Comment: @nf071590 I've got the same problem because I use `usePreview: true,`, when I set it to false its working fine

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore unless you add a delay, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892092/how-to-avoid-need-for-end-user-to-manually-start-the-google-places-autocomplete?noredirect=1&lq=1